# Receiving array in PHP coming from a jquery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I am passing an array of values to PHP using a jquery on multiple checkboxes:

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' class='regularCheckbox' name='color[]' value='".$colorBoxes[color_base1]."' /><font class='similarItemsText'>   ".$colorBoxes[color_base1]."</font><br />";
```

Jquery looks as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("input:checkbox").change(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) 
            {
            var color = [];
            color.push($(this).val());
            $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php?color='+color);
            }
});
});
```

And then I am receiving the array in a PHP with a `$color = $_GET['color'];`. Would this suffice to have  the array and use a `foreach($color as $value) {` to use my multiple values?

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever send more than one color at a time to PHP since you clear the JS color array each time that change handler is called.  Given the way color is passed in the query string to PHP, it doesn't appear PHP would be receiving an array either, since it would have to be `indexMain.php?color[]=blue&color[]=red` in order to be an array.

Comment: Why do you create a javascript array with one value only? And then you convert it into a string (which I think does not even work with javascript)? Please check your code example first. For multiple values, there is the jquery form serialize function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using `.load()` you should create a `.post(), .get(), or .ajax()` to send your data. For instance:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("input:checkbox").change(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            // not really sure why you are creating a new, empty array 
            // every time and only passing one color...
            var color = [];
            color.push($(this).val());
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "indexMain.php",
                data: {color: color},
                success: function(output) {
                    // load the textbox that 'indexMain.php' is outputting 
                    $(".indexMain").html(output);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```